# How do people in developing countries buy Bitcoin?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, banks, india

When there are only bank accounts of small bank institutes in undeveloped countries, how do people there buy Bitcoins? When there are only limited possibilities for global money exchange, how can people there participate in Bitcoin?